# I am using an accelerometer as an input and a stepper motor as an output and it will have these weird delays after about 30 sec

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer, stepper-motor

I have a stepper motor (kysan 1124090) turning CW and CCW based on the y direction of my accelerometer(MU6090). I am using an Arduino uno. It works great but after about 30 seconds there will be these pauses in the communication between the accelerometer and the stepper motor every 3-4 seconds. I can turn rotate the accelerometer and the stepper wont move for about half a second. I am wondering if its a storage issue, where after a while it has stock piled so much data that it needs that delay to keep it alive? When I verify the sketch it says I am only using 31% of the program storage space and 27% of dynamic memory. Maybe there is a way to get rid of all the data i dont need every time i run through my loop to get rid of this problem? I am attaching the code along with this. If anyone has any advice or things I could try, that would be awesome. Thanks.

```
#include <Wire.h>

#include "Kalman.h" 

#define RESTRICT_PITCH 

Kalman kalmanX; 
Kalman kalmanY;


double accX, accY, accZ;
double gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
int16_t tempRaw;

double gyroXangle, gyroYangle;
double compAngleX, compAngleY;
double kalAngleX, kalAngleY; 

uint32_t timer;
uint8_t i2cData[14]; // Buffer for I2C data

Stepper stepper2(200, 8, 10, 9, 11);
int cantidad = 1;

int previous = 0;
void setup() {
 
  stepper2.setSpeed(350);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  TWBR = ((F_CPU /400000L) - 16) / 2; // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz

  i2cData[0] = 7; 
  i2cData[1] = 0x00; 
  i2cData[2] = 0x00;
  i2cData[3] = 0x00; 
  while (i2cWrite(0x19, i2cData, 4, false)); 
  while (i2cWrite(0x6B, 0x01, true)); 

  while (i2cRead(0x75, i2cData, 1));
  if (i2cData[0] != 0x68) { // Read "WHO_AM_I" register
    Serial.print(F("Error reading sensor"));
    while (1);
  }

  delay(100); 
 
  while (i2cRead(0x3B, i2cData, 6));
  accX = (i2cData[0] << 8) | i2cData[1];
  accY = (i2cData[2] << 8) | i2cData[3];
  accZ = (i2cData[4] << 8) | i2cData[5];


#ifdef RESTRICT_PITCH // Eq. 25 and 26
  double roll  = atan2(accY, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan(-accX / sqrt(accY * accY + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#else // Eq. 28 and 29
  double roll  = atan(accY / sqrt(accX * accX + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan2(-accX, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#endif

  kalmanX.setAngle(roll); // Set starting angle
  kalmanY.setAngle(pitch);
  gyroXangle = roll;
  gyroYangle = pitch;
  compAngleX = roll;
  compAngleY = pitch;

  timer = micros();
}

void loop() {

  while (i2cRead(0x3B, i2cData, 14));
  accX = ((i2cData[0] << 8) | i2cData[1]);
  accY = ((i2cData[2] << 8) | i2cData[3]);
  accZ = ((i2cData[4] << 8) | i2cData[5]);
  tempRaw = (i2cData[6] << 8) | i2cData[7];
  gyroX = (i2cData[8] << 8) | i2cData[9];
  gyroY = (i2cData[10] << 8) | i2cData[11];
  gyroZ = (i2cData[12] << 8) | i2cData[13];

  double dt = (double)(micros() - timer) / 1000000; 
  timer = micros();

#ifdef RESTRICT_PITCH // Eq. 25 and 26
  double roll  = atan2(accY, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan(-accX / sqrt(accY * accY + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#else // Eq. 28 and 29
  double roll  = atan(accY / sqrt(accX * accX + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan2(-accX, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#endif

  double gyroXrate = gyroX / 131.0; // Convert to deg/s
  double gyroYrate = gyroY / 131.0; // Convert to deg/s

#ifdef RESTRICT_PITCH
//Serial.print("kalAngle is:"); Serial.print(kalAngleX);
  if ((roll < -90 && kalAngleX > 90) || (roll > 90 && kalAngleX < -90)) {
     
    kalmanX.setAngle(roll);
    compAngleX = roll;
    kalAngleX = roll;
    gyroXangle = roll;
  } else
    kalAngleX = kalmanX.getAngle(roll, gyroXrate, dt); 

  if (abs(kalAngleX) > 90)
    gyroYrate = -gyroYrate; 
  kalAngleY = kalmanY.getAngle(pitch, gyroYrate, dt);
#else

  if ((pitch < -90 && kalAngleY > 90) || (pitch > 90 && kalAngleY < -90)) {
    //Serial.print("pitch:"); Serial.println(pitch);
    kalmanY.setAngle(pitch);
    compAngleY = pitch;
    kalAngleY = pitch;
    gyroYangle = pitch;
  } else
    kalAngleY = kalmanY.getAngle(pitch, gyroYrate, dt); 

  if (abs(kalAngleY) > 90)
    gyroXrate = -gyroXrate; 
  kalAngleX = kalmanX.getAngle(roll, gyroXrate, dt); 
#endif

  gyroXangle += gyroXrate * dt; 
  gyroYangle += gyroYrate * dt;


  compAngleX = 0.93 * (compAngleX + gyroXrate * dt) + 0.07 * roll; 
  compAngleY = 0.93 * (compAngleY + gyroYrate * dt) + 0.07 * pitch;


  if (gyroXangle < -180 || gyroXangle > 180)
    gyroXangle = kalAngleX;
  if (gyroYangle < -180 || gyroYangle > 180)
    gyroYangle = kalAngleY;


#if 0 // Set to 1 to activate
  /*Serial.print(accX); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accY); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accZ); Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(gyroX); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroY); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroZ); Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print("\t");*/
#endif


 // Serial.print(kalAngleX); Serial.print("\t");

 // Serial.print("\t");

 // Serial.print(kalAngleY); Serial.print("\t");

#if 0 
  //Serial.print("\t");

  //double temperature = (double)tempRaw / 340.0 + 36.53;
  //Serial.print(temperature); Serial.print("\t");
#endif

  //Serial.print("\r\n");


int valuex = kalAngleX;  
//Serial.print("Valx:"); Serial.println(valuex);

stepper2.step(valuex - previous);


  previous = valuex;



}
```

Comment: the accelerometer does not communicate with the stepper motor ... the accelerometer communicates with the arduino ... the arduino controls the motor

Comment: right sorry, i was skipping the middle step. Do you have any ideas for the problem I am running into?

Comment: a lot of beginners read these posts ... some would think that a sensor is directly connected to the motor

Comment: isolate the area of failure ... try making the motor position independent of sensor readings .... maybe use millis() to determine motor position ... see if it still pauses

Comment: how would millis() work, doesnt that just have to do with keeping track of time?

Comment: i have not examined your code logic in detail ... maybe one of the `if` statements is getting an unexpected value .... put in some debugging `Serial.print()` statements

Comment: millis()/1000 would give you seconds ... use the value to move the stepper motor ... it should move every second ... basically use anything other that the sensor data to keep the motor moving ... if it does not stop as it did before, then that means it was previously commanded to stop

Comment: yeah that makes sense, okay i will try to make this work. Thank you

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to move the motor only based on only the millis(), is there any more help you can provide?